# How to convert a timestamp into a readable format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm trying to convert a timestamp into a readable format using the following code from `[timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

at the moment it appears as: 01.01.1970 and the timeStamp string looks like "2013-07-19T17:19:06+02:00";

```
    NSString * timeStampString = [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
    NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSString *_date=[_formatter stringFromDate:date];


    cell.timeStampLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_date ];
```

Comment: what is the question? `01.01.1970` is readable format acc. to me? how do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: I think you might be looking for [`NSDateFormatter's DateFormatterStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateFormatterStyle)

Comment: @SrikarAppal when I format the  [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; output everything shows up as '01.01.1970' instead of the real date from [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: What does timeStampString contain ? I assume that doubleValue returns 0 for your strings.

Comment: @MartinR the timestamp string looks like this: "2013-07-19T17:19:06+02:00";

Comment: Then you have to convert that string to NSDate using a suitable date formatter. Sorry, but there must be *many* duplicate Q&A's. - Did you expect that `doubleValue` magically converts that string to a time interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```

There are different date formatter styles which you would like to use :

- NSDateFormatterShortStyle
- NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
- NSDateFormatterLongStyle

Incase you have time also and you want to style it

```
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```

I hope this helps